# Set input values when one input value change JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now, when the 1st row value change, the 2nd and 3rd row change accordingly.
The problem is this's hard code, i don't know the no of rows as it's generated from the database.Any idea?Many thanks

```js
$("#A1").keyup(function() {
    $("#B1").val($("#A1").val());
});

$("#A1").keyup(function() {
    $("#C1").val($("#A1").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>    
<td><input type="text" id="A1" name="A" value=""></td>
</tr><br>
<tr>    
<td><input type="text" id="B1" name="A" value=""></td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr>    
<td><input type="text" id="C1" name="A" value=""></td> 
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different from other answers given here, changing **all** input elements is too risky in my opinion. What I would suggest id adding a `class` to all input fields you wish to change, and changing your function to a JQuery selector according to this class (In the example below, the class I added is called `changable`).

```js
$("#A1").keyup(function() {
    $(".changable").val($("#A1").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>    
<td><input type="text" id="A1" class="changable" value=""></td>
</tr><br>
<tr>    
<td><input type="text" id="B1" class="changable" value=""></td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr>    
<td><input type="text" id="C1" class="changable" value=""></td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: @tam Happy to help, happy coding.

Comment: @KobyDouek  don't you think input:first selector is even better in the sense that adding class to all is not necessary?BTW your solution is right

Answer (score 4):

you can just select all inputs and update values for all.

```js
$("#A1").keyup(function() {
    $("input").val($("#A1").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>    
<td><input type="text" id="A1" name="A" value=""></td>
</tr><br>
<tr>    
<td><input type="text" id="B1" name="A" value=""></td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr>    
<td><input type="text" id="C1" name="A" value=""></td> 
</tr>
```

Also if you want to select a few you can select multiple ids separated by commas. like this:

```
$("#A1").keyup(function() {
    $("#B1, #C1").val($("#A1").val());
});
```

Comment: @tam  it's again a specific (hard-code) example not generic.As you said that rows generated dynamically through db

Comment: That's right, thx for the reminder. The things is i just realize that in my code there's only one row of html written as the other rows is generated through while loop of the db query. it seems these answer cannot apply, any suggestion?

Comment: oh i think i figure that out, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the value to all the inputs in your HTML, like this:

```js
$("#A1").keyup(function() {
    $("input").val($("#A1").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>    
<td><input type="text" id="A1" name="A" value=""></td>
</tr><br>
<tr>    
<td><input type="text" id="B1" name="A" value=""></td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr>    
<td><input type="text" id="C1" name="A" value=""></td> 
</tr>
```